# Reverse number with while loop

Tags: java

I have been studying programmin for 3 months and I don't have a lot of experience so my question maybe silly for someone. This code I wrote in order to read the number in reverse won't run and there is no syntac errors.

```
public class fdujfdryujhftyh {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=8023;
        int rev=a%10;
        a=a/10;
        while(a!=0); {
            rev=rev*10+a%10;
            a=a/10;
        }
        System.out.println("Reverse number is"+rev);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: What does `won't run` mean?

Comment: what IDE are you using? As running java code can require slightly different IDE configurations.

Answer (score 4):

remove the ";" in  "while(a!=0); {"

i think you have made a endless loop so no system.out is shown

You wrote something that is equivalent to

```
while(a!=0){
  //Do Nothing endless
}

{
     rev=rev*10+a%10;
     a=a/10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too

```
int a=8023;

System.out.println("Reverse: " + new StringBuilder(a + "").reverse().toString());
```

I think you want to make it using math operations, but this way is valid for me. Regards!